# Is it possible to specifically replace the contents of a group in a regular expression?

Tags: regex

I need to locate, uncomment and replace the variable values (using Ansible) a section in telegraf.conf file:

```
  ## HTTP Basic Auth
  # username = "telegraf"
  # password = "metricsmetricsmetricsmetrics"
```

with this

```
  ## HTTP Basic Auth
    username = "myusername"
    password = "anotherpassword"
```

I am able to find the original block with

```
(^.+HTTP Basic Auth\R.+)#( username = ").+("\R.+)#( password = ").+(")
```

And make the substitutions with

```
\1 \2myusername\3 \4anotherpassword\5
```

But I find it very counterintuitive to have *to group the parts I don't want to replace*, instead of just the bits that need to be modified. It's like I'm making a negative match of the expression to replace the other bits.

This other expression would create groups only for the parts that need to be edited:

```
^.+HTTP Basic Auth\R.+(#) username = "(.+)"\R.+(#) password = "(.+)"
```

Also this creates one less group and I find the expression easier to read.
But I cannot find documentation or examples/solutions online for a substitution expression that would specifically indicate what should be the new content of each group.

Is this just not how substitutions were designed to work, or is there a method to accomplish this?

Comment: not sure if I understood you correctly, but isn't it easier to read line by line, and check the first chars of it matches ## if it does't, it would indicate that its a line that you need to work on the replaces? such as removing the # and adding the \1, \2 etc?

Comment: Reading line by line is besides the point. The file is very long and has lots of repetitive sections. I'm matching a multi-line block as a fail-safe to edit just the one section that needs to be modified, instead of inadvertently introducing unwanted modifications in other parts of the file. Also there are 2 lines next to each other that need to be edited and this way I can change both values in one step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to thank https://stackoverflow.com/users/211627/jdb for the helpful discussion, but ultimately this is what currently makes sense in my mind to directly answer the question. Feel free to comment.

Strictly within regexp, groups within a matched expression can be modified with an uppercase or lowercase transformation ( \U\1 and \L\1 respectively, for group 1) but there are no other tokens that would codify for other modifications of the contents of a group.

So the answer is no. To routinely modify parts of matched regular expression by indicating a substitution regexp, one must create groups for the parts that do not need modification; and in the substitution expression, recreate the original expression by placing the original groups in sequence, introducing the modified text between the groups. There is no need to create groups for the parts to be modified, as these groups will not be referenced in the substitution regexp. The solution `\1 \2myusername\3 \4anotherpassword\5` indicated in the question exemplifies this procedure.

Answer (score 1):

The sole job of a regex is to match a pattern. You come along later and do something interesting with the data about the matched pattern, but regex itself only matches.

A single regex can only match a single pattern. You have two parts of a string that you want to replace, so you need to decide whether you want to match both the user name and password in a single regex and thus handle the replace with a single line of code, or if you would prefer to break it up into one pattern for each which would simplify the regexes and require two separate replacements.

I think maybe the most helpful thing you're missing is [lookaround groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Using a zero-width lookbehind group you can find a pattern which is prefixed by a pattern without actually "matching" the prefix.

For example, if I want to find `D` prefixed by `E`, but I only want to match (and thus replace) `D`, I can use the following regex:

```
(?<=E)D
```

Given the following input:

```
ADBDCDED
```

my regex will only match the last `D`. All of the other `D`'s would fail because they aren't prefixed by an `E`. However, only the `D` is matched, not the `E`.

It looks like Ansible uses python regexes, so you have to refer to [python's documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) about what patterns are acceptable.

Unfortunately, python only supports fixed length patterns in a lookbehind, meaning that you can use something like `a|b` but not `a*`. I don't think that will be a problem for you so long as you feel confident that your user name is always prefixed by `username =`

So, long story short, you can use a pattern like this to find your user name:

```
(?<=username = ")[^"]+
```

Which will look for `username = "` and then match all of the following characters until a `"` is found.

You can repeat this pattern for the password as well:

```
(?<=password = ")[^"]+
```

Comment: I think I get your points. But for example I can isolate 'telegraf' as a group (group \2 in my 3rd expression) and modify it directly to uppercase with a substitution expression \U\2 but I cannot assign another arbitrary value for that group (within regexp)?

Comment: Just think of the regex happening first, and then the replace is a totally different tool that takes the result of your regex and gives you some tools around that. In fact, if you notice, the "code" for the replace is completely different from the regex. The replace will take, and this is important, _everything that your regex matched_ and replace it with whatever text you provide. However, the replace feature gives you the ability to get text from the match (via groups) and even do some basic modifications to it. But you are replacing the _entire match_, not individual groups.